# Who made those 1:50,000 maps in 1930's China

Tags: china, communism

Gong Chu in his [Memoir](https://books.google.com/books?id=j38HAQAAIAAJ&dq=inauthor%3A%22Chu%20Gong%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%E5%9C%B0%E5%9C%96) mentioned several times Red Army officers poring over 1:50,000 maps of the most backward areas of China in early 1930s. I wonder who could possibly make those maps.

Comment: Not for sure but I would imagine it was the Jesuit missionaries, i have several old maps of theirs, none at that exact scale though but close.

Comment: What evidence says the answer is anything other than a national cartography bureau? It seems at least as plausible that the Red Army was able to clandestinely get some government maps, than that it was able to create them itself.

Comment: China between 1911 and 1930s consisted of dozens of war lords big and small constantly switching alliances; there was no national anything to speak of. Before 1911, China was a medieval country. But I'd be fascinated if these maps were indeed made by a Chinese government.

Comment: I think it is a mistake by one zero. Maps with the scale of 2cm/km are very thorough and very expensive. Or they were maps for some special region.

Answer (score 5):

The maps may have been made by the New Army, specifically the Military Survey and Mapping Academy. Quoting from [a book by Nicolas Schillinger](https://books.google.com/books?id=moZwDQAAQBAJ):

> [M]ilitary reformers and New Armies leaders attached great importance
>   to surveying, mapping, and cartography (*cehui* or *celiang*). The
>   *Detailed and Illustrated Manual*, for instance, included a substantial chapter on military maps (*cehui tushuo*). Yuan et al.
>   [1899] 1992, 991–1022. A central Military Survey and Mapping Academy
>   (*Cehui xuetang*) was officially set up in February 1906, and numerous
>   articles in a variety of military journals discussed the advantages of
>   cartography and reprinted regulations concerning surveying ...

Comment: This is indeed fascinating. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: And where is a word about 1:50000 scale?